# Local DNS Server: What's the best name practice for accessing projects under local domain?

Tags: domain-name-system

I usually setup a local DNS Server to resolve locally first, forwarding after to a public DNS.

My schema uses the following naming convention (I prefix ongoing projects with "development" as subdomain):

http://www.foo.com

http://development.foo.com

I've noticed that other people would do http://www.foo.com.local is there a reason for this ? Is my approach wrong ?

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using .local is wrong - that domain is specifically for local multicast DNS names as specified in [RFC 6762](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc6762.html), which says

> This document specifies that the DNS top-level domain ".local." is a
>      special domain with special semantics, namely that any fully
>      qualified name ending in ".local." is link-local, and names within
>      this domain are meaningful only on the link where they originate.

It's common to use some form of subdomain to differentiate between development, testing and production. Exactly how these domains are named differs, but it's fairly common to have e.g.

```
Production:          www.example.com
Performance testing: www.pt.example.com
Testing:             www.test.example.com
Development:         www.dev.example.com
```

The reason to not just replace `www` with `development` is that you may want to have more than one subdomain - e.g. you may have `mobile.example.com` in addition to `www.example.com`. By using the above scheme, you would then have

```
Production:          www.example.com          mobile.example.com
Performance testing: www.pt.example.com       mobile.pt.example.com
Testing:             www.test.example.com     mobile.test.example.com
Development:         www.dev.example.com      mobile.dev.example.com
```